# XSLT - Updating the Header

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

The request XML i have is given below and the XSLT transformation Iam using is also given.  Unfortunately the ordertotal xml tag is repeating twice after transformation. How can i update the existing tag rather than inserting double tag

Request XML is

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:fetchOrderListResponse xmlns:ns2="http://impl.lob.wipro.com/">
         <return>
            <customerOrderNumber>1</customerOrderNumber>
            <orderDetails>
               <itemPrice>50.0</itemPrice>
               <itemQty>2</itemQty>
               <itemUnit>0</itemUnit>
               <orderDetailsId>37516016-D71B-4790-951F-55D00B0CC159</orderDetailsId>
               <camelAddedDtlField>0.1</camelAddedDtlField>
            </orderDetails>
            <orderDetails>
               <itemPrice>39.0</itemPrice>
               <itemQty>3</itemQty>
               <itemUnit>0</itemUnit>
               <orderDetailsId>6095ABC7-0D0D-4B2E-92E5-80F24E9092B8</orderDetailsId>
               <camelAddedDtlField>0.1</camelAddedDtlField>
            </orderDetails>
            <orderId>84EC371D-40CA-455E-A0FA-7EA733E9BFD3</orderId>
            <ordertotal>0.0</ordertotal>
            <camelAddedHdrField>0.0</camelAddedHdrField>
         </return>
         <return>
            <customerOrderNumber>1</customerOrderNumber>
            <orderId>54712493-2172-4ADB-814B-BC7AA0BB72C3</orderId>
            <ordertotal>0.0</ordertotal>
            <camelAddedHdrField>0.0</camelAddedHdrField>
         </return>
         <return>
            <customerOrderNumber>1</customerOrderNumber>
            <deliverydate>2013-02-06T00:00:00+05:30</deliverydate>
            <orderDetails>
               <itemPrice>565.0</itemPrice>
               <itemQty>1</itemQty>
               <itemUnit>0</itemUnit>
               <orderDetailsId>9A5030BE-F95F-4C62-B5A2-41FF85423218</orderDetailsId>
               <camelAddedDtlField>0.1</camelAddedDtlField>
            </orderDetails>
            <orderDetails>
               <itemPrice>4.0</itemPrice>
               <itemQty>90</itemQty>
               <itemUnit>0</itemUnit>
               <orderDetailsId>65A8B3BE-D407-43D8-8754-EA1E26AA56E4</orderDetailsId>
               <camelAddedDtlField>0.1</camelAddedDtlField>
            </orderDetails>
            <orderId>0BDCB222-0117-47A9-8813-DF03A1D19E5E</orderId>
            <ordertotal>0.0</ordertotal>
            <camelAddedHdrField>0.0</camelAddedHdrField>
         </return>
         <return>
            <customerOrderNumber>1</customerOrderNumber>
            <orderId>8E4220DC-884B-47BC-A565-E26B80BA5249</orderId>
            <ordertotal>0.0</ordertotal>
            <camelAddedHdrField>0.0</camelAddedHdrField>
         </return>
         <return>
            <customerOrderNumber>1</customerOrderNumber>
            <deliverydate>2013-02-06T00:00:00+05:30</deliverydate>
            <orderDetails>
               <itemPrice>10.0</itemPrice>
               <itemQty>4</itemQty>
               <itemUnit>0</itemUnit>
               <orderDetailsId>5A2DF895-BB0F-4039-80DB-F44CED31697B</orderDetailsId>
               <camelAddedDtlField>0.1</camelAddedDtlField>
            </orderDetails>
            <orderDetails>
               <itemPrice>20.0</itemPrice>
               <itemQty>3</itemQty>
               <itemUnit>0</itemUnit>
               <orderDetailsId>8034FBF4-B573-4B19-BDF5-FAF6C4247A55</orderDetailsId>
               <camelAddedDtlField>0.1</camelAddedDtlField>
            </orderDetails>
            <orderId>60161E3E-3C4A-4CE6-AAC3-E4D2BC240046</orderId>
            <ordertotal>0.0</ordertotal>
            <camelAddedHdrField>0.0</camelAddedHdrField>
         </return>
      </ns2:fetchOrderListResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

XSLT is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="return">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*|*" />
<ordertotal>
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(orderDetails/(itemPrice*itemQty))" />
            </ordertotal>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Response XML Is showing with duplicate tag is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:fetchOrderListResponse xmlns:ns2="http://impl.lob.wipro.com/">

         <return>
            <customerOrderNumber>1</customerOrderNumber>
            <orderDetails>
               <itemPrice>50.0</itemPrice>
               <itemQty>2</itemQty>
               <itemUnit>0</itemUnit>
               <orderDetailsId>37516016-D71B-4790-951F-55D00B0CC159</orderDetailsId>
               <camelAddedDtlField>0.1</camelAddedDtlField>
            </orderDetails>
            <orderDetails>
               <itemPrice>39.0</itemPrice>
               <itemQty>3</itemQty>
               <itemUnit>0</itemUnit>
               <orderDetailsId>6095ABC7-0D0D-4B2E-92E5-80F24E9092B8</orderDetailsId>
               <camelAddedDtlField>0.1</camelAddedDtlField>
            </orderDetails>
            <orderId>84EC371D-40CA-455E-A0FA-7EA733E9BFD3</orderId>
            <ordertotal>0.0</ordertotal>
            <camelAddedHdrField>0.0</camelAddedHdrField>
            <ordertotal>217</ordertotal>
         </return>
         <return>
            <customerOrderNumber>1</customerOrderNumber>
            <orderId>54712493-2172-4ADB-814B-BC7AA0BB72C3</orderId>
            <ordertotal>0.0</ordertotal>
            <camelAddedHdrField>0.0</camelAddedHdrField>
            <ordertotal>0</ordertotal>
         </return>
         <return>
            <customerOrderNumber>1</customerOrderNumber>
            <deliverydate>2013-02-06T00:00:00+05:30</deliverydate>
            <orderDetails>
               <itemPrice>565.0</itemPrice>
               <itemQty>1</itemQty>
               <itemUnit>0</itemUnit>
               <orderDetailsId>9A5030BE-F95F-4C62-B5A2-41FF85423218</orderDetailsId>
               <camelAddedDtlField>0.1</camelAddedDtlField>
            </orderDetails>
            <orderDetails>
               <itemPrice>4.0</itemPrice>
               <itemQty>90</itemQty>
               <itemUnit>0</itemUnit>
               <orderDetailsId>65A8B3BE-D407-43D8-8754-EA1E26AA56E4</orderDetailsId>
               <camelAddedDtlField>0.1</camelAddedDtlField>
            </orderDetails>
            <orderId>0BDCB222-0117-47A9-8813-DF03A1D19E5E</orderId>
            <ordertotal>0.0</ordertotal>
            <camelAddedHdrField>0.0</camelAddedHdrField>
            <ordertotal>925</ordertotal>
         </return>
         <return>
            <customerOrderNumber>1</customerOrderNumber>
            <orderId>8E4220DC-884B-47BC-A565-E26B80BA5249</orderId>
            <ordertotal>0.0</ordertotal>
            <camelAddedHdrField>0.0</camelAddedHdrField>
            <ordertotal>0</ordertotal>
         </return>
         <return>
            <customerOrderNumber>1</customerOrderNumber>
            <deliverydate>2013-02-06T00:00:00+05:30</deliverydate>
            <orderDetails>
               <itemPrice>10.0</itemPrice>
               <itemQty>4</itemQty>
               <itemUnit>0</itemUnit>
               <orderDetailsId>5A2DF895-BB0F-4039-80DB-F44CED31697B</orderDetailsId>
               <camelAddedDtlField>0.1</camelAddedDtlField>
            </orderDetails>
            <orderDetails>
               <itemPrice>20.0</itemPrice>
               <itemQty>3</itemQty>
               <itemUnit>0</itemUnit>
               <orderDetailsId>8034FBF4-B573-4B19-BDF5-FAF6C4247A55</orderDetailsId>
               <camelAddedDtlField>0.1</camelAddedDtlField>
            </orderDetails>
            <orderId>60161E3E-3C4A-4CE6-AAC3-E4D2BC240046</orderId>
            <ordertotal>0.0</ordertotal>
            <camelAddedHdrField>0.0</camelAddedHdrField>
            <ordertotal>100</ordertotal>
         </return>
      </ns2:fetchOrderListResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you already have present an ordertotal element in your source XML, instead of matching result and creating the new ordertotal element, just match the ordertotal element by using the following template.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="ordertotal">
         <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(../orderDetails/(itemPrice*itemQty))" />
         </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```